# Does Bootstrap Tour allow error message validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, bootstrap-tour

I'm using Bootstrap tour but the issue is that I need to only tour/highlight fields that are incorrect. The problem with Bootstrap tour is that hardcode all of your element id's or classnames. The form errors that I have are based off of incorrect fields. So I can't hard code the field ID's since I won't know which fields are incorrect until a user fills out a form.

```
// Instance the tour
    var tour = new Tour({
    backdrop: true,
    steps: [
    {
      element: "#primary-address-line-label-2",
      title: "Title of my step",
      content: `<h3 class="tool-tip-title">Review/Update Your Address</h3>
      <div class="tip-content">
      <p>Our records indicate the address we have on file for you may be incorrect.</p>
      <p>Please make any edits in the field below. Click "Save & Continue" once you are finished.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="number-of-actions">1 of 5 Actions</div>`,
      placement: "top"
    }
  ]});


  // Initialize the tour
  tour.init();

  // Start the tour
  tour.start();
```

My html is:

```
<div>
  <label>City</label>
 <input class="form-control" type="text" id="City" class="error"><span style="display: inline-block;">City is required.</span>
 </div>

<div>
  <label>City</label>
 <input class="form-control" type="text" id="State" class="error"><span style="display: inline-block;">State is required.</span>
 </div>
```

As you can see from my example about city and state fields have an error class and are incorrect but any field could be incorrect based off of user input.

Does Bootstrap tour have the ability to create dynamic elements/ steps based off of fields that are incorrect?

Are there any other jQuery or JavaScript plugins that Validate Fields with tooltips?

Bootstrap Tour is located [here](http://bootstraptour.com/api/)

Answer (score 3):

hey man i was looking for your dude and in the official API about Boostrap Tour they dont show any thing about  validation this is the  official site  of the API http://bootstraptour.com/api/

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! When providing a link to documentation, please briefly illustrate why you are referencing it. This could be by giving a quick code example, or quoting a specific paragraph. "Just RTFM!" is rarely going to help the OP in their search for the problem. Also, if the answer makes sense to you, it is more likely it will make sense to others (I'm _not_ sure what "dude" you were looking for :) )